# Instance attributes inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make it so when an instance of Customers is created and the restaurant they are going to is specified the number_served instance attribute of that instance of the Restaurant class is incremented by the number of customers going to the restaurant.

I am not sure if the number_served should be a class or instance attribute (i think class) and I am not sure how I can inherit the attribute from the Restaurant class to the Customers class so I can increment it.

```
class Restaurant:



    def __init__(self,name,restaurant_type,cuisine_type):
        self.name = name 
        self.restaurant_type = restaurant_type
        self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type
        self.number_served = 0 


    def describe_restaurant(self):
        print(f"{self.name} is {self.restaurant_type} which serves {self.cuisine_type}.")

    def open_restaurant(self):
        print(f"{self.name} is open.")

    def get_number_served(self):
        print(f"{self.number_served} customers served at the {self.name} today.")

    def increment_number_served(self,num):
        self.number_served += num

class Customers(Restaurant):

    def __init__(self,where_eating,no_of_people):
        self.where_eating = where_eating
        self.no_of_people = no_of_people

    def go_eat(self):
        self.increment_number_served(self.no_of_people)
```

I basically want the number_served attribute of a restaurant instance to be incremented by the number of customers who went to the restaurant from an instance of the Customers class

Comment: Why is `Customers` inheriting from `Restaurant` in the first place? A customer is not a kind of restaurant.

Comment: Instead, `Customers.go_eat` should take a `Restaurant` instance as an argument, and the `increment_number_served` method of that instance should be invoked.

Comment: Python does not automatically call the parent class `__init__` constructor. You need to use `super().__init__(...)` to correctly initialize instances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A customer is not a type of restaurant, so inheritance is not appropriate here. The `go_eat` method should take an instance of `Restaurant` as an argument instead.

```
class Restaurant:
    def __init__(self, name, restaurant_type, cuisine_type):
        self.name = name 
        self.restaurant_type = restaurant_type
        self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type
        self.number_served = 0 

    def describe_restaurant(self):
        print(f"{self.name} is {self.restaurant_type} which serves {self.cuisine_type}.")

    def open_restaurant(self):
        print(f"{self.name} is open.")

    def get_number_served(self):
        print(f"{self.number_served} customers served at the {self.name} today.")

    def increment_number_served(self,num):
        self.number_served += num


r = Restaurant("...", "...", "...")


class Customers:

    def __init__(self, no_of_people):
        self.no_of_people = no_of_people

    def go_eat(self, restaurant):
        restaurant.increment_number_served(self.no_of_people)


c = Customers(9)
c.go_eat(r)
```

If you want `Customers` to represent not just a group of diners, but rather a group of diners going to  particular restaurant, then pass `r` to `__init__`:

```
class Customers:

    def __init__(self, where, no_of_people):
        self.where = where
        self.no_of_people = no_of_people

    def go_eat(self):
        self.where.increment_number_served(self.no_of_people)


c = Customers(r, 9)
c.go_eat()
```

Comment: What's that `::` after Customers @chepner